# Create unique string C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to write a program that reads from a text file the first and last name. Then, I need to take up to 4 charaters of the first name and 4 charaters of the last name and combine them into a third string. The issue is that the new string must be unique.
eg.

First name = James
Last name = Jackson

new string would be JAMEJACK

First name = James
Last name = Jack

new string = JAMEJACK1
or new string = JAMSJACK

It doesn't matter how it is done, as long as all of the strings are unique.

```
        LastName = input.Substring(12, 10);

        FirstName = input.Substring(21, 21);
        new string = LastName.Substring(0, 4) + FirstName.Substring(0, 4);
```

I know this probably isn't the best way to do this but I'm still new at this.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if the names are less than 4 characters?

Comment: It would just uses what is there. The length isn't that important. It just needs to be unique.

Comment: There's no way we can know what will be unique without knowing the dataset.  Is there a reason you don't just append a random number to ensure uniqueness?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. but that would work.

Comment: @Amy: Surely a non-random number... A random number has a chance of being matched, if you just use consecutive numbers then you can guarantee you won't use the same number again...

Comment: @Chris: Yes if the string matched another string in the file, add a 1. If a third string matched, add a 2... Something of that sort. I'm not sure how to write it

Comment: @imsohappy You could use a list, so whenever you make a new string you add it to that list. When you go to make a new string, check to see if that string is in the list. You could use the index as the last number identifier as well to make it easier, as you won't ever have any matching names.

Comment: Do it in three steps 1) Create new string for each row 2) Sort by new string 3) Add suffix if two consecutive rows contain same new string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam Marion really gets the credit here for being the first to suggest it, but it was also the same line of thinking I had.

Why not use a `Dictionary<string, int>` to store all the combined names, and the count of how many there are.  Then once you build the Dictionary, you can just increment the number by how many duplicates you have.  Something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> usernameCollection = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach(string name in namesTextFile)
{
    string username = string.Concat(name.Split().Select(x => x.Length >= 4 ? x.Substring(0, 4) : x));

    if(usernameCollection.ContainsKey(username))
    {
        usernameCollection[username] = usernameCollection[username] + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        usernameCollection.Add(username, 1);
    }                   
}
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZOrSZ3) to demonstrate.

Comment: Edit: Sorry I misread the fiddle. Thanks for the shout out. Good answer!

Comment: @maccettura how would I use your suggestion when I need to read the string from a file?

Comment: @imsohappy `File.ReadAllLines()` returns an array of string.  If your names are in a text file, each on a new line than just use that.

Comment: Thank you!! maccenttura and @Sam Marion your answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do the trick. I added some comments to it, and tried to explain it as simple as i could.

```
var uniqueList = new HashSet<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) //just for testing purposes
{
    string firstName = "James"; //first name
    string lastName = "Jackson"; //last name

    string shortFN = (firstName.Length >= 4) ? firstName.Substring(0, 4) : firstName; //check for name with 4 or less chars
    string shortLN = (lastName.Length >= 4) ? lastName.Substring(0, 4) : lastName; //with "true", it uses the whole name

    string newShortName = shortFN + shortLN; //adding up the words

    if (uniqueList.Contains(newShortName)) //find if its unique to the list of names
    {
        //not unique
        var repeatedNames = uniqueList.Count(x => x.Contains(newShortName)); //this will get how many names in the list are repeated
        newShortName += repeatedNames; //we add the number
        uniqueList.Add(newShortName); //now the name is unique, so we add it
    }
    else
    {
        uniqueList.Add(newShortName); //adding the new name to the list of names
    }
}
```

Comment: So your solution is to just keep adding `1` to the end of strings?

Comment: well, i just read that it should be adding numbers depending in how many names are repeated. let me try to update my answer.

Comment: You might want to consider a `HashSet<string>` rather than a `List<string>`. `HashSet.Contains` should be much faster than `List.Find`...

Comment: shouldn't it be a 'while' loop instead of an if. To me it seems newShortName += "1" will always create JAMEJACK1 since newShortName will always be JAMEJACK.

Comment: It seems like a Dictionary<String, int> would work best. With int being num count that you can just keep incrementing?

Comment: @SamMarion has the best solution IMO.  Increment on duplicates, then at the end just dump all entries of the Dictionary, appending `0-n` at the end

Comment: @Chris you were right, thanks! I updated the answer to match the request of incremental numbers.

Comment: @SamMarion making a dictionary just to have a number seems a little excessive. I already updated my answer to get that "added number" at the end without a dictionary

Comment: @FireFrog your solution is to use `Count()`?  So you want to iterate over the collection for every loop?  _That_ seems a "little excessive"

Answer (score 0):

You can't ensure uniqueness without being able to compare to previous entries.

The simplest way I can think of doing this is to enter each entry you make into a list, and then when you make a new entry, compare it to every other entry in the list for uniqueness, regenerating where necessary.

No doubt there are better and more efficient ways of doing this, but think a simple answer will serve better here.

Here's a pseudo code example:

```
List<string> CompareList = new List<string>();
        //...however you're gonna loop this

        string LastName = input.Substring(12, 10);

        string FirstName = input.Substring(21, 21);
        string generatedName = LastName.Substring(0, 4) +
                               FirstName.Substring(0, 4);
        bool nameIsUnique = true;

        foreach (var entry in CompareList)
        {
            if (entry == generatedName) nameIsUnique = false;
        }

        if (nameIsUnique) CompareList.Add(generatedName);
        else //Go back to generating a name, add a number on the end, etc
        //Go to next line in your text file, rinse, repeat.
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
    var names = new List<Name>
    {
        new Name { FirstName = "AAA", LastName = "BBB"  },
        new Name { FirstName = "AAA", LastName = "BBB"  },
        new Name { FirstName = "CCC", LastName = "DDD"  }
    };

    var trimmedNames = names.Select(x => new Name { FirstName = x.FirstName.Substring(0, 4), LastName = x.LastName.Substring(0, 4) });

    var grouped = trimmedNames.GroupBy(x => new { x.FirstName, x.LastName });
    var result = grouped.SelectMany(x => 
    {
        var uniqueNames = new List<string>();

        if (x.Count() > 1)
        {
            var index = 1;

            foreach (var singleName in x)
            {
                uniqueNames.Add($"{singleName.FirstName}{singleName.LastName}{index++}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            uniqueNames.Add($"{x.Key.FirstName}{x.Key.LastName}");
        }

        return uniqueNames;
    }).ToList();
```

Result:

```
AAABBB1
AAABBB2
CCCDDD
```

Or even simpler:

```
    var result = grouped.SelectMany(x => 
    {
        var uniqueNames = new List<string>();

        var index = 1;

        foreach (var singleName in x)
        {
            uniqueNames.Add($"{singleName.FirstName}{singleName.LastName}{index++}");
        }

        return uniqueNames;
    });
```

But produces a slightly different result:

```
AAABBB1
AAABBB2
CCCDDD1
```

Comment: This is good for strings less than 4 characters but has no checks strings over 4 characters long.

Comment: @SamMarion I'm sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: The requirement was to trim first or last names to 4 character length. Your example assumes the user has already done that which is fine, just though it would be good to add to your answer.

Comment: @SamMarion Ah, I didn't realize that was a challenge too :) Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party but this is a version of @maccettura's answer. Instead of taking a direct substring, this makes up random substrings from first and last names, then adds a count if still unique.

```
public class Program
{
    // Take distinct set of random numbers in a given range
    public static List<int> GetDistinctRandomNumbers(int min, int max, int count)
    {
        // Must do error checks for if (min > max) etc...
        var rnd = new Random();
        var val = Enumerable.Range(min, max).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next());
        return val.Take(count).ToList();
    }

    // Get a substring of a string composed by extracting characters from given indices
    public static string GetStringByIndices(string str, List<int> indexes)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        foreach (var index in indexes)
            result += str[index];
        return result;
    }

    public static string CreateRandomString(string str1, string str2)
    {
        // Number of characters to extract from each string
        int len1 = (str1.Length < 4) ? str1.Length : 4;
        int len2 = (str2.Length < 4) ? str2.Length : 4;

        // Indices at which characters will be extracted from each string
        var str1Indexes = GetDistinctRandomNumbers(0, str1.Length, len1);
        var str2Indexes = GetDistinctRandomNumbers(0, str2.Length, len2);

        // Extracted strings
        var first = GetStringByIndices(str1, str1Indexes);
        var second = GetStringByIndices(str2, str2Indexes);

        // Potentially unique string
        return first + second;
    }

    public static void CreateUniqueList(string strToAdd, ref Dictionary<string,int> dict)
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(strToAdd))
            dict.Add(strToAdd, 1);  // If not found in the dictionary, add it, with a count of 1
        else
        {
            int count;
            if (dict.TryGetValue(strToAdd, out count))
            {
                dict.Add(strToAdd + count.ToString(), count + 1);   // If found, add a new item where NewKey = ExistingKey + Count
                dict[strToAdd] += 1;    // Increment count of existing Key
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> unique = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var str = CreateRandomString("Jennifer", "Lawrence");
            CreateUniqueList(str, ref unique);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Admittedly this doesn't really give you any particular advantage (I guess), it was just fun writing this.

Comment: You must move `var rnd = new Random();` outside of the method to ensure you don't get repeated values.

Answer (score -1):

I do like the GUID option. you can use the 4 characters of the first and last name as part of a seed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace randomseed
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string first = "fir";
        string last = "LastName";
        string firstlast = first.Substring(0, first.Length > 4 ? 4 : first.Length)
            + last.Substring(0, last.Length > 4 ? 4 : last.Length);
        int seed = 0;
                    string uniqueString = firstlast + GenerateStringNameGuid(seed);
        string u2 = firstlast + GenerateStringNameGuid(seed);
        string u3 = firstlast + GenerateStringNameGuid(seed);

        Console.Write($"uniqueString = { uniqueString} \n");
        Console.Write($"uniqueString = { u2} \n");
        Console.Write($"uniqueString = { u3} \n");



    }

    public static string GenerateStringNameGuid(int seed)
    {
        var r = new Random(seed + Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        var guid = new byte[16];
        r.NextBytes(guid);

        return new Guid(guid).ToString();
    }
}
```

}

output

```
uniqueString = firLast7e7d1ec5-a375-3384-7e39-89859fa55d6f
uniqueString = firLast047f91be-3f7c-e0aa-414e-ece64bf6833f
uniqueString = firLast00042b27-0afa-fd92-c127-95bd84235040
```

Comment: This does not solve the OP's problem at all.  They want a list of names that combine the first 4 letters (or less if the name isnt 4 characters) of the first and last name, then add a (1, 2, 3, etc) at the end for duplicate entries.

Comment: just adding that now

Comment: Also, if I where to guess (I could be wrong) this seems like something to create unique user names. I don't think users would appreciate logging in with those names... Otherwise totally works and is fine.

Comment: @maccettura OP is reading text from a file and trying to generating uniqueness.

Comment: @Sam Marion They are user names. I just can't have the same one for two people.